# Chrome Extension Options Page: <select> dropdown not working or appears black

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been looking all over the internet for how to fix this strange behavior:

Since the latest Chrome 78 update, my Chrome extentension options page  dropdowns don't work anymore. Dropdowns (with `<option>` + `<select>`) either don't react to clicking at all or appear black whenever they actually do show the dropdown:

[image]

I encounter this on 3 different machines, all using Win10 + Chrome 78. Last I checked, this wasn't present with Chrome 77. **Is this a configuration issue? Is this perhaps a Chrome 78 bug?**

I isolated a minimal extension example consisting of two files:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Minimal Extension",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "settings.html",
    "chrome_style": true
  }
}
```

settings.html (copied from https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>My Test Extension Options</title></head>
<body>

Favorite color:
<select id="color">
 <option value="red">red</option>
 <option value="green">green</option>
 <option value="blue">blue</option>
 <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="like">
  I like colors.
</label>

<div id="status"></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See https://crbug.com/1015298. The fix had landed in Canary, dev, beta channels but not in the stable channel so you'll have to wait for a month or so. I don't know if there's a workaround other than using a custom dropdown list library.

Comment: Seems that google search and chromium issue search have failed me this time, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wOxxOm has commented, this is indeed a bug that was already reported: https://crbug.com/1015298